# How to replace "-" with "_" in url before mapping a controller and an action in a .net mvc3 application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, replace, custom-routes

Hello everyone :I am working on a .net mvc3 application.
Here is my controller and action :

```
public class Foo_Bar : Controller
{
     public ViewResult Foo_Bar()        
    {

        return View();
    }
}
```

And my corespondent view file is : Foo_Bar.cshtml

now ,my question is : I have a url as: www.mystite.com/foo-bar/foo-bar
but this url can not invoke the Foo_Bar/Foo_Bar controller and action except I write it as thes: www.mystite.com/foo_bar/foo_bar .

Now I need to replace the "-" with "_" before the route system mapping my controller and action. Can I do it in the routes.MapRoute()? Some one please help me .Thank you advance !ps:this is my first time to ask an question in  Stack overflow:)

Comment: Argh, there is an attribute for this. It is just at the tip of my tongue and I can't remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `RouteHandler` to change the values for `{action}` and `{controller}`.  First, create your RouteHandler, as follows:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;  
using System.Web.Routing;  

public class MyRouteHandler : IRouteHandler  
{  
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)  
    {  
        var routeData = requestContext.RouteData;  
        var controller = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString(); 
        routeData.Values["controller"] = controller.Replace("-", "_");  
        var action = routeData.Values["action"].ToString();  
        routeData.Values["action"] = action.Replace("-", "_");  
        var handler = new MvcHandler(requestContext);  
        return handler;  
    }  
}
```

Then, change your Default route as follows:

```
routes.Add("Default",  
    new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}",  
        new RouteValueDictionary(  
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),  
            new MyRouteHandler() 
        ) 
    );  
);
```

When a request is satisfied by this route, the RouteHandler will change the dashes to underbars.

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute [ActionName]

```
public class Foo_Bar : Controller
{
     [ActionName("foo-bar")]
     public ViewResult Foo_Bar()        
    {

        return View();
    }
}
```

There isn't an equivalent for Controllers, so you can't use it in your route with {controller}. But you can define it explicitly at least.