# Attach parameters to ActionLinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to attach a parameter to every single @Html.ActionLink without changing the code in the view file?

Something like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    RouteData.Values.Add("param_name", "param_value"); // This does not work
    return View();
}
```

I want all the links to contain the parameter:

```
<a href="/controller/action/1?param_name=param_value">test</a>
```

Session is not a good option because users can open multiple windows in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this in the controller? With `@Html.ActionLink` its as simple as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Controller", 
                 new { id = 1, param_name = "param_value" })
```

This should generate:

```
<a href="/Controller/Edit/1?param_name=param_value">Edit</a>
```

If for some reason this is not applicable to your project you should be able to do this with routing.

Comment: I want to attach this parameter to all links on the page, including links defined on layout page, partial views etc.

Comment: @Corneliu you may want to try creating your own route handler like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708155/how-to-replace-with-in-url-before-mapping-a-controller-and-an-action-in) suggests.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible on the route level, see [ASP.NET MVC: The right way to propagate query parameter through all ActionLinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442494/asp-net-mvc-the-right-way-to-propagate-query-parameter-through-all-actionlinks/9442562). If you want to do it on `Action`/`View` level, then you can probably still make a route class that will generate URLs based on some data set by controller.